# If $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d|(xa+yb)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Where all numbers are positive integers and $x$ and $y$ can be any number. I realize that this is of course true but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If $d | a$, then there is an integer $k$ for which $a = dk$. If $d | b$, there is an integer $m$ for which $b = dm$. Then

$$xa + yb = x \cdot dk + y \cdot dm = d(xk + ym)$$

So what can you conclude from this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$. Then there exists $k_{a},k_{b}$
s.t. $a=k_{a}d$ and $b=k_{b}d$. Note that $xa+yb=xk_{b}d+yk_{a}d=d\left(xk_{b}+yk_{a}\right)$
and hence $d\mid\left(xa+yb\right)$.